# midiOutOpen is returning an unknown error when I call it from Julia code

Tags: c, windows, winapi, julia

I'm trying to send midi messages from some Julia code I've written, but I'm having trouble with the midiOutOpen function. I'm following this tutorial [here](http://blog.fourthwoods.com/2011/12/23/playing-midi-files-in-windows-part-1/), but the output I'm getting from the function doesn't make sense.

This is my Julia code:

```
const CALLBACK_NULL = uint32(0x00000001)
function openoutputdevice(id::Uint32)
    handle = uint32(0)

    err = ccall((:midiOutOpen, :Winmm), stdcall,
        Uint32,
        (Ptr{Uint32}, Uint32, Ptr{Uint32}, Ptr{Uint32}, Uint32),
         &handle,     id,     C_NULL,      C_NULL,      CALLBACK_NULL)

    println(hex(err))
    handle
end
```

The handle is always 0, and the error that's being returned is "10". I've grepped through the Windows header files, and this doesn't seem to match up with any of the errors that can be expected from the function (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd798476(v=vs.85).aspx)), so I'm more inclined to think that I'm mapping the wrong Julia data types in the ccall. It's been a long time since I've done anything C-related, so I'm hoping there's something obviously wrong with this. The only odd thing I've seen is that CALLBACK_NULL is defined in mmsyscom.h as 0x000000001 - a 9 digit hex number, even though the function doc specifies a DWORD for the final parameter to midiOutOpen.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is `MMSYSERR_INVALFLAG` because `CALLBACK_NULL`  is defined as:

`#define CALLBACK_NULL       0x00000000l`

That is a lowercase-letter-"L" at the end, not the number 1 (one). The call succeeds when this value is corrected.